# Can't upload file using file.transferTo(dest) in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

It not show any error or warning message it execute successfull and return to the jsp page.
But the page is not able to load css.
In My project I am using spring security also.
My controller is below

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/doUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
  public String importQuestion(@Valid @RequestParam("fileName") MultipartFile file, @ModelAttribute("questionDetails") QuestionDetails questionDetails,
      BindingResult result, ModelMap model) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
    String uploadPath = context.getRealPath("") + "static" + File.separator + "tempFile" + File.separator;

    File dest = new File(uploadPath);
    file.transferTo(dest);
    return "importQuestion";
  }
```

Comment: If this is the only page not loading css then provide the configuration code else check configuration file for resource handler

Comment: ok but file is also not uploaded at the destination.

Comment: have you get the image bytes in the server side after uploading

Comment: I am not check that but get the name of the file on server.

Comment: Try checking whether you are receiving the byte stream. And your code seems to have no `HttpServletRequest` in paramater. Add `HttpServletRequest` to get byte streams from the request.

Comment: so, i need to add HttpServletRequest into the method parameter

Comment: The bytes streams of the uploaded image is accessible via request as a byte stream. please try adding `HttpServletRequest `

Comment: It not working. it not generate any error or warning. but can't upload file

Comment: did you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in html form.

Comment: yes, i did it..

Comment: What exactly your multipart file holds.

Comment: It hold excel file

Comment: Yours code seems like no image bytes are received. change `MultipartFile` to `multiPartFile[]`. And you are getting string values other than image bytes. please try this.

Comment: it also can't work.

Comment: It create file instead of folder. My program is send a excel file into to folder but after run the program it become folder to file.